# php and mysql counting amount

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to display the amount of a certain pokemon that is in the game by the name of the pokemon and by the type, ( there is two types normal and shiny ) I want it to only grab one type hard to explain... right now its grabing both types and I don't know why here's my code :/

```
$sql23 = "
    SELECT * FROM user_pokemon
    WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION['username']."'AND (slot='1')
";
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM user_pokemon
    WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='1')
");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$count = mysql_query("
    SELECT count(*) FROM user_pokemon WHERE pokemon='".$row['pokemon']."
    'AND type='".$row['type']."'
");
$count2 = mysql_fetch_array($count);
```

I honestly don't understand why it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated :)

`$row['pokemon']` is the name of the pokemon

`$row['type']` is the type of the pokemon (shiny, normal, ect..)

`user_pokemon` table as asked:

```
Field       Type          Null      Default        Comments
-----------------------------------------------------------
id          int(11)       No                       
hp          int(55)       No        30             
pokemon     varchar(50)   No                       
belongsto   varchar(50)   No                       
exp         int(50)       No        500            
item        varchar(50)   No        No Item        
nickname    varchar(50)   No        No Nickname    
move1       varchar(50)   No        Ember          
move2       varchar(50)   No        Ember          
move3       varchar(50)   No        Ember          
move4       varchar(50)   No        Ember          
slot        int(50)       No                       
level       int(90)       No        5              
time_stamp  timestamp     No        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
gender      varchar(25)   No        Male           
type        varchar(55)   No        Normal         Type: normal/shiny etc
safari_zone int(10)       No        0
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Reminding you to put space before AND in all queries.

Comment: Can you put up the schema and some sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Could you post the structure of the `pokemon` and `user_pokemon` tables

Comment: just an advice.... you seem to lack the base in php. it will be better if you start with something simpler.

Comment: You would be better off using joins

Comment: I don't know what joins are i just started learning a few days ago.

Comment: @itachi how can it get any simpler than pokemons ? :) Can't agree with you, IMHO it's better to jump in and debug..

Comment: @enrey he is assiging the statement to a variable but in the query, he is writing the whole statement again.... so definitely he has lack of knowlede of variable advantages.... `count` and `join`s are little bit avanced commands. He will just copy/paste and replace the names, fields from one of the answers. It will work but he will have no clue how the results are obtained.

Comment: @itachi I think that `COUNT` and `JOIN`s are not advanced commends, As a beginer, he should learn them. Or at least we should point out to them.

Comment: @itachi that's what we all did one day. Better learn it on pokemons, I guess it's just fun, no bussiness. Confession: I still do copy-paste sql snippets from manuals, because I just can't grasp the syntax right.

Comment: sorry for wasting all your guys time XD it was a easy mistake on my part I figured it out :/ but thanks for all the advice :)

Comment: Looks like `$_SESSION{'username'}` should have square brackets in it. @user1908445, don't forget to explain what the problem was in the answer box below - consider that the price of asking a question! `:)`

Comment: About your table: 11 is max for integers and 255 is max for varchars. If you need more you have to work with longintegers. I don't think you have over 1 billion levels. When you have 50 levels you have int(2).

Comment: @jordi12100: The max for `varchar` is 65535 since MySQL 5.0.3. It uses two length bytes if the length can be more than 255. And both `int(11)` and `int(2)` can hold the same values. The difference is only seen when the column is `zerofill` (which you don't want).

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I regularly see on StackOverflow is lack of code formatting. In my view fixing this is a great way to make your code much more readable both to yourself (aids learning) and to others (aids your readers here). It additionally reduces the need for horizontal scrolling, allowing you to place several editors side-by-side on your screen.

Here is your code with suggested code formatting:

```
$sql23 = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        user_pokemon
    WHERE
        belongsto = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
        AND (slot = '1')
";
$result = mysql_query($sql23) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name = '{$row['pokemon']}'
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $battle_get = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $count = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            user_pokemon
        WHERE
            pokemon='{$row['pokemon']}'
            AND type='{$row['type']}'
    ");
    $count2 = mysql_fetch_array($count);
}
```

This helped indicate that your `while` was missing a closing brace, and that the variable `$sql23` wasn't actually used. Also note that you can use array values inline in double-quoted strings, by wrapping them in braces.

As noted in the comments, you should upgrade to PDO or mysqli. Also, be careful about injecting values directly into the SQL if they have come from the user, as this can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Look into query parameterisation, or at least untainting, to ensure your code is safe.